# Svg image is not showing in jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, html, svg, knockout.js, d3.js

I am using jquery accordion. I have inserted a table inside it. In that table there are two columns. 1st column will show an svg element and 2nd one will show text. I have binded the text data by using knockoutjs and it works fine. but how can i bind an svg element with 1st column. I want to bind svg element by d3js preferably but any other way will also be appreciated

```
<table id="AccordionTable">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:Items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="I Want to bind here an svg element dynamically"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:Name" style="padding-left: 15px"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: code here :<table id="AccordionTable">
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach:Items">
                                <tr>
                                    <td data-bind="I Want to bind here an svg element dynamically">
                                    
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-bind="text:Name" style="padding-left: 15px">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

Comment: What did you try to show the SVG?

Comment: i made a svg tag and bind it with column by using knockout's html binding. like :- var ui = "<svg height=20 width=20><circle r=10 cx=10 cy= 10 fill='green'></svg>"; it works but it create svg tag for every element. but i want only one svg surface.

Comment: Maybe you can demonstrate the problem on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). I have done something similar using Raphael.js with Knockout

```
<td data-bind="createSvg: parameter"></td>

ko.bindingHandlers.createSvg = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
{
    var options =
        {
            strokeWidth: 5,
            boxBackgroundColour: $('.navbar-inner').css('background-color'),
            positiveFeed: '#00bb00',
            negativeFeed: '#bb0000'
        };
    var substation = new Substation(element, options);
    viewModel.Substation = substation;
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
{
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.LastUpdated);
    if ($(element).is(':visible'))
    {
        var substation = viewModel.Substation;
        if (viewModel.RtuUserData)
        {
            substation.set(element, viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

};

The init method is called once, to create it, and then the update method is called every time the LastUpdated property on my view model is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yup ! this also may be the way.But in this meantime i totally changed my approach. Now i am not binding svg element instead of this i am creating the svg element just there i wanted to bind them.Thanks again . :)